# List comprehension in haskell with let and show, what is it for?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm studying project euler solutions and this is the solution of problem 4, which asks to

> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
>   numbers

```
problem_4 =
  maximum [x | y<-[100..999], z<-[y..999], let x=y*z, let s=show x, s==reverse s]
```

I understand that this code creates a list such that `x` is a product of all possible `z` and `y`.

However I'm having a problem understanding what does `s` do here. Looks like everything after `|` is going to be executed everytime a new element from this list is needed, right?

I don't think I understand what's happening here. Shouldn't everything to the right of `|` be constraints?

Comment: `x` is the product of all possible `z`, `y`? Now it aims to construct products that are palindromes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I meant that the list would have all the products but anyways I think even this interpretation is wrong

Comment: x is the product of all possible y and z where z >= y and x is a palindrome (that is what s does). The maximum of the list is the largest palindrome of such products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list comprehension is a rather thin wrapper around a `do` expression:

```
problem_4 = maximum $ do
     y <- [100..999]
     z <- [y..999]
     let x = y*z
     let s = show x
     guard $ s == reverse s
     return x
```

Most pieces translate directly; pieces that aren't iterators (`<-`) or `let` expressions are treated as arguments to the `guard` function found in `Control.Monad`. The effect of `guard` is to short-circuit the evaluation; for the list monad, this means not executing `return x` for the particular value of `x` that led to the false argument.

Comment: So lists comprehensions are actually translated to this?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Yes, list comprehensions are syntactic sugar for `do`-notation specifically for lists.

Comment: There's also the [`MonadComprehensions`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/MonadComprehensions) extension for general monads, not just lists.

Comment: I don't see why monads and do notation are introduced here. They aren't necessary. See the translation given in the Haskell Language report: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11. Most introductory texts introduce list comprehensions before monads.  Ch. 5 in Programming in Haskell by Hutton and Ch. 4 in Bird, Thinking Functionally with Haskell

Answer (score 5):

> I don't think I understand what's happening here. Shouldn't everything to the right of `|` be constraints?

No, at the right part you see an expression that is a comma-separated (`,`) list of "parts", and every part is one of the following tree:

1. an **"generator"** of the form `somevar <- somelist`;
2. a **`let` statement** which is an expression that can be used to for instance introduce a variable that stores a subresult; and
3. expressions of the type boolean that act like a **filter**.

So it is not some sort of "*constraint programming*" where one simply can list some constraints and hope that Haskell figures it out (in fact personally that is the difference between a "programming language" and a "specification language": in a programming language you have "control" how the data flows, in a specification language, that is handled by a system that reads your specifications)

Basically an iterator can be compared to a "foreach" loop in many imperative programming languages. A "let" statement can be seen as introducing a temprary variable (but note that in Haskell you do *not* assign variable, you declare them, so you can not reassign values). The filter can be seen as an `if` statement.

So the list comprehension would be equivalent to something in Python like:

```
for y in range(100, 1000):
    for z in range(y, 1000):
        x = y * z
        s = str(x)
        if x == x[::-1]:
            yield x
```

We thus first iterate over two ranges in a nested way, then we declare `x` to be the multiplication of `y` and `z`, with `let s = show x`, we basically convert a number (for example `15129`) to its string counterpart (for example "15129"). Finally we use `s == reverse s` to reverse the string and check if it is equal to the original string.

Note that there are more efficient ways to test Palindromes, especially for multiplications of two numbers.

Comment: FWIW, in Haskell lingo, `x <- e` is called a _generator_. (& congratulations for having reached 100k :-)) (already +1d yesterday)